# javascript always return false in my case

Tags: javascript

I am writing code for recursion. And here is my code.

Here, what I am trying to do is, if string has `'` then replace it with HTML quotes and calling function recursively until all `'` have been replaced.

But this is always returning me false. When I alert `var a`. If I not use `return false` then it returns undefined. Any clue what is the wrong here?

```js
var a = replaceqt(" hello's there 'how are you?' ");
console.log(a);
function replaceqt(object) {
  var indexc = object.indexOf("'");

  var next = object.charAt(indexc + 1);
  var prev = object.charAt(indexc - 1);
  if (indexc == 0) {
    object = object.replace("'", "&lsquo;");
  } else if (parseInt(prev) >= parseInt(0) && parseInt(prev) <= parseInt(9)) {
    object = object.replace("'", "&#39;");
  } else if (next == " ") {
    object = object.replace("'", "&rsquo;");
  } else if (prev == " ") {
    object = object.replace("'", "&lsquo;");
  } else {
    object = object.replace("'", "&rsquo;");
  }
  indexc = object.indexOf("'");
  if (indexc > -1) {
    replaceqt(object);
    return false;
  } else {
    return object;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are returning false whenever there is a second call. Should return the result of recursive invocation instead.

```js
var a = replaceqt(" hello's there 'how are you?' ");
console.log(a);
function replaceqt(object) {
  var indexc = object.indexOf("'");

  var next = object.charAt(indexc + 1);
  var prev = object.charAt(indexc - 1);
  if (indexc == 0) {
    object = object.replace("'", "&lsquo;");
  } else if (parseInt(prev) >= parseInt(0) && parseInt(prev) <= parseInt(9)) {
    object = object.replace("'", "&#39;");
  } else if (next == " ") {
    object = object.replace("'", "&rsquo;");
  } else if (prev == " ") {
    object = object.replace("'", "&lsquo;");
  } else {
    object = object.replace("'", "&rsquo;");
  }
  indexc = object.indexOf("'");
  if (indexc <= -1) {
    return object;
  }
  return  replaceqt(object);
}
```

BTW you don't need `parseInt(num)` if `num` is a `number` say 0 or 9.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
if (indexc <= -1){
    return object;
}else{
    replaceqt(object); return false;
}
```

with

```
if (indexc <= -1){
    return object;
}else{
    return replaceqt(object);
}
```

In your original code, the return value of `replaceqt(object)` is discarded when `indexc >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `.split` and `.join` functions to simplify your code.

---

For a simple **find-replace all**, you can do this:

```
var sentence = "I hate spaces."
var charToFind = " ";
var replacement = "-";

var afterSplit = sentence.split(charToFind) // ["I", "hate", "spaces"]
var result = afterSplit.join(replacement)   // "I-hate-spaces"
```

---

Your example is more complex than a find replace, because you need to keep track of left and right quotes.

To get around that, we can figure out if it's **even or odd using the index** in the array.

```js
var someString = "My 'name' is 'Ryan'... I 'think'."

function replaceQuotesFor (str) {
  return str
    .split("'")
    .map(function (str, index) {
      var quote = index % 2 === 1
        ? '&lsquo;'
        : '&rsquo;'
      
      return (index === 0)
        ? str
        : quote + str
    })
    .join('')
}

console.log('Before:', someString)
console.log('After:', replaceQuotesFor(someString))
```

---

I stopped using `for` loops and modifying indices, because it made debugging frustrating.

I hope these functions help simplify your code and help you in the future!

Comment: thanks man, i have some complex format here, suppose if `'` comes after any number then it should stay same.

Comment: What would be your desired output for `I like the 'number' '2'`?